# PC crashes after PCI-Port Timeout

Tags: crash, pci

Sometimes my PC crashes suddenly. With no specified reason. Sometimes it happens while playing games or just watching a YouTube video.
Now I found some logs which in my opinion shows what is wrong but, I don't know how to fix it.

```
19:40:42 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:03.1: AER:    [12] Timeout               
19:40:42 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:03.1: AER:    [12] Timeout               
19:40:42 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:03.1: AER:    [ 8] Rollover              
19:40:42 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:03.1: AER:   device [1022:1453] error status/mask=00001100/00006000
19:40:42 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:03.1: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
19:40:38 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:03.1: AER:    [12] Timeout               
19:40:38 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:03.1: AER:   device [1022:1453] error status/mask=00001000/00006000
19:40:38 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:03.1: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
```

Comment: Looks like failing hardware.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `lspci -nn` and `lspci -tv` and `ifconfig` and `iwconfig`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.